# Vue.js mutation observer

Tags: vue.js

I made a modal in my website keyboard focussed, in vue.js but there is button in the modal which is disabled until you type something in the input field in the modal, now when I press Tab after inputting something in the text input field the button is enabled however pressing tab button doesn't bring that particular button in focus , I used mutation observer to catch the changes in the buttons attribute but I can't figure out what code to write in the callback function that runs  when a mutation is observed

the mounted method of the vue file is as follows:-

```
mounted() {
// Listen to keydown events on the document
this.focusableElements = 'button:not([disabled]), [href], input:not([disabled]), select, textarea, [tabindex]:not([tabindex="-1"])';
this.modal = document.querySelector('.modal-dialog');
this.focusableContent = this.modal.querySelectorAll(this.focusableElements);
this.firstFocusableElement = this.focusableContent[0];
this.lastFocusableElement = this.focusableContent[this.focusableContent.length - 1];
document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyPress);
this.firstFocusableElement.focus();
this.targetNode = document.querySelector('.modal-footer');
this.config = { attributes: true };

this.callBack = function(mutationsList, observer) {
  for( const mutation of mutationsList ) {
    if ( mutation.type === 'attributes' ) {
      document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyPress);
    }
  }
};
this.observer = new MutationObserver(this.callBack);
this.observer.observe(this.targetNode, this.config);
```

}

the onKeyPress methods is as follows:-

```
onKeyPress(e) {
  const isTabPressed = e.key === 'Tab' || e.keyCode === 9;
  if (!isTabPressed) {
    return;
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 27 || e.key === 'Escape') {
    this.close();
  }
  if (e.shiftKey) { // if shift key pressed for shift + tab combination
    if (document.activeElement === this.firstFocusableElement) {
      this.lastFocusableElement.focus(); // add focus for the last focusable element
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  } else if (document.activeElement === this.lastFocusableElement) {
    this.firstFocusableElement.focus();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
},
```

Comment: Please provide a code snippet or better link to the minimal reproducible part. It is hard to answer you without it.

Comment: i edited the question you can now see the code snippet

Comment: Hey, your code does not leverage a lot of Vue build-in tools, you can check my code here and see if this helps -> https://jsfiddle.net/lightning00blade/1motzs8y/1/. I think is on a better track of what you are trying to do.